# Removing rows with less than x consecutive non NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a data frame with a time_date index and 29 columns of data. The data frame has isolated Non-NaN values, which I want to remove (or convert into NaN) and only keep rows with, let's say  at least 5 consecutive values. For example, initially, I have:

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18/01/2018 7:00 | NaN | NaN | 3.493148804 | -3.861461957 |
| 19/01/2018 6:00 | 0.000643658 | NaN | 4.493148804 | -3.861461957 |
| 19/01/2018 7:00 | 0.003109299 | NaN | 7.247741699 | -4.749528885 |
| 19/01/2018 8:00 | 0.003109299 | -0.031979417 | NaN | -3.726334095 |
| 19/01/2018 9:00 | 0.003109299 | -0.031979417 | NaN | 0.13656346 |
| 19/01/2018 10:00 | NaN | -0.031979417 | NaN | 2.823025544 |
| 19/01/2018 11:00 | NaN | -0.031979417 | NaN | 3.529650052 |
| 19/01/2018 12:00 | NaN | -0.038014129 | 0.006496742 | 4.243628979 |
| 19/01/2018 13:00 | -0.003737779 | NaN | -0.003895367 | 5.595969041 |
| 19/01/2018 14:00 | -0.003999399 | NaN | -0.013323511 | 6.294107278 |
| 19/01/2018 15:00 | -0.003999399 | 2.823025544 | -0.026859129 | 5.231494427 |
| 19/01/2018 16:00 | -0.003999399 | 3.529650052 | -0.031979417 | 5.075140158 |
| 19/01/2018 17:00 | -0.003999399 | NaN | -0.038014129 | 4.057830334 |
| 19/01/2018 18:00 | -0.003999399 | NaN | NaN | 4.384686947 |

What I want is something like this:

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18/01/2018 7:00 | NaN | NaN | NaN | -3.861461957 |
| 19/01/2018 6:00 | NaN | NaN | NaN | -3.861461957 |
| 19/01/2018 7:00 | NaN | NaN | NaN | -4.749528885 |
| 19/01/2018 8:00 | NaN | -0.031979417 | NaN | -3.726334095 |
| 19/01/2018 9:00 | NaN | -0.031979417 | NaN | 0.13656346 |
| 19/01/2018 10:00 | NaN | -0.031979417 | NaN | 2.823025544 |
| 19/01/2018 11:00 | NaN | -0.031979417 | NaN | 3.529650052 |
| 19/01/2018 12:00 | NaN | -0.038014129 | 0.006496742 | 4.243628979 |
| 19/01/2018 13:00 | -0.003737779 | NaN | -0.003895367 | 5.595969041 |
| 19/01/2018 14:00 | -0.003999399 | NaN | -0.013323511 | 6.294107278 |
| 19/01/2018 15:00 | -0.003999399 | NaN | -0.026859129 | 5.231494427 |
| 19/01/2018 16:00 | -0.003999399 | NaN | -0.031979417 | 5.075140158 |
| 19/01/2018 17:00 | -0.003999399 | NaN | -0.038014129 | 4.057830334 |
| 19/01/2018 18:00 | -0.003999399 | NaN | NaN | 4.384686947 |

The real number of required consective rows is 24. So any non NaN values less than 24 are converted  into NaN. In other words, I only want episodes having length of at least 24 in my data. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom function to mask values is the consecutive non-NA are less than N, then `apply` to all columns:

```
def mask_below(s, N=5):
    m1 = s.isna()
    m2 = s.groupby(m1.cumsum()).transform('count').ge(N)
    return s.where(m1|m2)

df.set_index('Date').apply(mask_below).reset_index()
```

output:

```
                Date         A         B         C         D
0    18/01/2018 7:00       NaN       NaN       NaN -3.861462
1    19/01/2018 6:00       NaN       NaN       NaN -3.861462
2    19/01/2018 7:00       NaN       NaN       NaN -4.749529
3    19/01/2018 8:00       NaN -0.031979       NaN -3.726334
4    19/01/2018 9:00       NaN -0.031979       NaN  0.136563
5   19/01/2018 10:00       NaN -0.031979       NaN  2.823026
6   19/01/2018 11:00       NaN -0.031979       NaN  3.529650
7   19/01/2018 12:00       NaN -0.038014  0.006497  4.243629
8   19/01/2018 13:00 -0.003738       NaN -0.003895  5.595969
9   19/01/2018 14:00 -0.003999       NaN -0.013324  6.294107
10  19/01/2018 15:00 -0.003999       NaN -0.026859  5.231494
11  19/01/2018 16:00 -0.003999       NaN -0.031979  5.075140
12  19/01/2018 17:00 -0.003999       NaN -0.038014  4.057830
13  19/01/2018 18:00 -0.003999       NaN       NaN  4.384687
```

Comment: @DeveloperKE Can you open a new question with a reproducible example of a dataset that fails?

Comment: @DeveloperKE that seems to be a different question, please open a new question with a well formatted reproducible minimal `DataFrame` input and the matching expected output, use the correct tags, etc. Ensure that your example is not working with the above code.